# Primeros pasos en Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Recientemente comencé a aprender un poco de Android y trabajo con AndroidStudio.

Tengo un proyecto que me sirve de estudio, pero fue desarrollado en Linux y yo utilizo Windows 8.1 al compilarlo me muestra el siguiente error:

> Error:(1, 0) Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details. This warning can be disabled by adding the line 'android.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the project directory.

Me gustaría que me ayudaran a resolverlo. Saludos

Comment: A mi me apareció este error cuando importé un proyecto de ejemplo que descargué y aún cuando lo movía de carpeta se volvía a direccionar a la carpeta "Descargas" donde lo había bajado y me seguía apareciendo el error, la solución fue que busqué el proyecto importado, en una carpeta diferente a la de descarga, entonces ahí ya no tuve problema, lo cambie de ruta sin signos especiales y funcionó a la perfección

Answer (score 4):

Esto curre cuando la ruta de tu projecto tiene caracteres no nativas del ingles como por ejemplo acentos. Tambien se han [reportado errores con path que tiene caracteres en chinos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33938096/3590533).

Por ejemplo:

```
C:/proyectos_android/información_medica/
```

Intenta moverlo a una ruta donde sea solo letras sin ningún otro caracteres especial ni acento.

```
  C:/proyectos_android/informacion_medica/
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya resolví el error.